# SignalR connection gets disconnected automatically after 2 sec

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, signalr-hub, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I am using signalR (Aspnetcore.SignalR.core v3.1.0) in one of my we application. In my local environment I am able to connect and maintain the connection between server and client. However when I deployed this app to IIS on windows server, the signalR is making connection and then automatically disconnects after 2 secs.

I tried to log the traced of both local and Server and found one discrepancy. Apart from that I am not able to find anything.

For the reference below are the traces
**1.  Trace from my local machine**

[2022-11-17T18:56:45.702Z] Debug: Selecting transport 'WebSockets'.
Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-17T18:56:45.703Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) Connecting.

Utils.ts:199 [2022-11-17T18:56:45.758Z] Information: WebSocket connected to ws://localhost:65109/XXXX/XXXXXXXX?id=_t1lt-2t0e0r4W5DZEmNLw.

Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-17T18:56:45.758Z] Debug: The HttpConnection connected successfully.

Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-17T18:56:45.758Z] Debug: Sending handshake request.

Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-17T18:56:45.759Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) sending data. String data of length 32.

Utils.ts:199 [2022-11-17T18:56:45.759Z] Information: Using HubProtocol 'json'.

Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-17T18:56:45.775Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) data received. String data of length 3.

Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-17T18:56:45.776Z] Debug: Server handshake complete.

Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-17T18:56:45.776Z] Debug: **HubConnection connected successfully.**

receipting.js:71 SignalR Connected.

Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-17T18:56:47.620Z] Trace: **(WebSockets transport) sending data. String data of length 86.**

Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-17T18:56:48.283Z] Trace: ***(WebSockets transport) data received. String data of length 44.***

Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-17T18:57:01.219Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) data received. String data of length 11.

Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-17T18:57:02.640Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) sending data. String data of length 11.

Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-17T18:57:16.221Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) data received. String data of length 11.

Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-17T18:57:17.647Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) sending data. String data of length 11.

Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-17T18:57:31.229Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) data received. String data of length 11.

Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-17T18:57:32.663Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) sending data. String data of length 11.

Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-17T18:57:46.231Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) data received. String data of length 11.

As highlighted above in bold my connection is successful and after that, The client is sending data of length 89 and then receiving data of length 44 from server.Further The connection continues exchanging keepalive packets.

**2. Traces from IIS deployed application (The one with issue)**

[2022-11-18T05:51:53.718Z] Debug: Selecting transport 'WebSockets'.
Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-18T05:51:53.719Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) Connecting.

Utils.ts:199 [2022-11-18T05:51:53.754Z] Information: WebSocket connected to ws://server Ip/Hubs/myHubName?id=XECmdzZutBdZup3AnyfzRw.

Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-18T05:51:53.754Z] Debug: The HttpConnection connected successfully.

Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-18T05:51:53.755Z] Debug: Sending handshake request.

Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-18T05:51:53.756Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) sending data. String data of length 32.

Utils.ts:199 [2022-11-18T05:51:53.756Z] Information: Using HubProtocol 'json'.

Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-18T05:51:53.779Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) data received. String data of length 3.

Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-18T05:51:53.780Z] Debug: Server handshake complete.

Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-18T05:51:53.780Z] Debug: **HubConnection connected successfully**.

receipting.js:71 SignalR Connected.
Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-18T05:51:55.691Z] **Trace: (WebSockets transport) sending data. String data of length 86.**

Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-18T05:51:57.746Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) socket closed.

Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-18T05:51:57.746Z] Debug: HttpConnection.stopConnection(undefined) called while in state Connected.

Utils.ts:199 [2022-11-18T05:51:57.746Z] Information: Connection disconnected.

Utils.ts:203 [2022-11-18T05:51:57.747Z] Debug: HubConnection.connectionClosed(undefined) called while in state Connected.

Now in this case the client sends the data of length 86, However unlike the first case there is nothing sent back by server to client. And then abruptly the socket closes and connection is terminated.

I am not aware what are those data which is being exchanged between client and server. I tried going through most available documents but no luck.

I tried changing Keepalive time and clientTimeout inerval in startup.cs, however it not helping me out. I also kept default standard values but same is the behaviour.

`

```
 services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
            {
                hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000); //10 secs
                hubOptions.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(110000); //110 secs

            })
            .AddJsonProtocol(options =>
            {
                options.PayloadSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
            });
```

`

Can someone please help me understand this behavior?

Comment: What the OS version in your server ?

Comment: Hi @JasonPan the OS is "Windows Server 2016 Standard"

Comment: Is the websocket protocol enabled? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support